# Serve Live Stream to Multiple client with a webcam and python on a browser

Tags: python, opencv, http-live-streaming

I want to create a website to broadcast live stream from a webcam on a browser with http to multiple client. I can serve video with following code to only one client succesfully;

```
def gen_frames():  
    while True:
        print(time.time())
        success, frame = camera.read()
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
```

in this point, I cant handle with multiple requests. With multiple request, I lost too many frame for each request because every request get one frame and this frame can not read by another request. if I store frame as a global variable, performance issues are occurs.